# How to add an ID attribute to script with HAML's :javascript filter

Tags: haml, backbone.js

I'm trying to follow this Rails/Backbone example but they are using erb and not haml. See lines 45-48 of

https://github.com/AndrewGertig/backbone-demo/blob/master/app/views/dogs/index.html.erb

It doesn't seem to be possible to add an :id attribute to script so it looks like...

```
<script id="dog_template" type="text/html">
  <td>{{name}}</td>
  <td>{{age}}</td>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%script{:id => "dog-template", :type => "text/html"}
  %td {{name}}
  %td {{age}}
```

You can try it out [here](http://haml-lang.com/try.html)

Comment: Obvious now I think about it. Thanks.

I guess this might be a problem if I'm putting anything other than a javascript template in there.

The alternative I found was to just use the :erb filter instead.

Comment: I prefer %script#dog-template over putting ids in the {}

Comment: Any way to write JSON code inside of the script tag? For details on what I mean, please see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636072/haml-json-add-a-script-tag-of-type-application-json.