# HAML | JSON: Add a Script Tag of Type Application/JSON

Tags: json, haml, multiline, script-tag

### Write a Script Tag With the Type Application/JSON

This is about as straight-forward as it sounds. I'd like the **HAML** equivalent of:

```
<script class="_config" type="application/json">
    {
        "template": "#myId",
        "css": {
            "background": "#fff",
            "opacity": "0.8"
        }
    }
</script>
```

As of now, the only solution is...

```
%script._config{ type: 'application/json' }
  { |
    "template": "#id", |
    "css": { "background": "#fff" } |
  }
```

... Which sucks -- it renders the JSON in the page. Also, there should be no need to write the 'multiline' pipes. If its `application/json`, why wouldn't HAML know to parse it without normal indentation rules?

Any way to write this without the need of pipe characters?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “it renders the JSON in the page”? When I try it renders the `script` tag around the contents, the same as your HTML (except for differences with newlines). What result are you expecting?

Comment: Hmmm.. Maybe something about my environment -- I'm getting the actual json text rendering into the page where this tag is declared. Just checked it again.

Comment: Do you have the json text properly indented under the script tag in your real code, perhaps you moved it when testing things?

Comment: Indentation all good. The only thing that's been working for me other that the multiline characters is using the `:plain` filter inside of `%script`.